# android notification not working on 5.0 onwards

Tags: android, notifications

Trying to get notifications to work on android project and cant seem to figure out why notifications are not working? it could be that I am missing something, or that something needs take out, but I cant figure out. could be that this project hasn't been touched in a few years.
Any help would be great! :)

```
private  void modifyNotification(String payload){       

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(payload.equalsIgnoreCase(""))clearNotifications();
        else if(payload.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))clearNotifications();
        else{   


            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this.ctx);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            notificationBuilder.setNumber(R.string.notification_tray_text);//Unsure until tested
            notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.ctx, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            String notificationText = this.ctx.getString(R.string.notification_text);
            notificationText = String.format(notificationText, payload);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.ctx, this.ctx.getString(R.string.notification_title), notificationText, pendingIntent);


            notification.number = Integer.parseInt(payload);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I belive you need 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
notificationManager = notificationBuilder.build();
}else{
notificationManager = notificationBuilder.getNotification();
}

Comment: *this project hasn't been touched in a few years* - so much has changed in that time, it might be easier to start from scratch instead of fixing old broken code piece by piece

Comment: better you go with this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: @Pavan Thanks! This Helped! :)

Comment: @welcome, glad to know it helped